# Remove cache for one particular page using PHP

Tags: php, html, flowplayer, browser-cache

I am using Flowplayer in my webpage. Once the video ends, I change to another video and restart the player. My issue occurs if I remove the first video and upload the second video while still playing the first video. If I clear the browser cache and again restart the player, then it plays the last uploaded file. Please guide me: is there is any other way to clear the cache of a particular page, or restart the Flowplayer cache?

Comment: How do you change the video when the first ends ?

Comment: through FTP i delete the 1st video and then upload the 2nd video in the given path

Comment: Meena, make sure the two videos have different file names and change the parameters to the player accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure each video have it's own URL**, and use this call to make sure the page in itself isn't cached:

```
header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: @Emil Vikström: The manual doesn’t. But there are some hints: First, having “session” in its name. Second: “The cache limiter is reset to the default value stored in *session.cache\_limiter* at request startup time. Thus, you need to call `session_cache_limiter()` for every request (and before `session_start()` is called).” And finally, you can look up the [source code of that function in session.c at line 1701](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/session/session.c?revision=307671&view=markup#1701). All it does is setting *session.cache\_limiter* for the runtime.

Comment: @Emil Vikström: It’s `session_start` that finally sets the corresponding header fields.

Comment: The first and second is obviously irrelevant as they only tell which module that handles it. Your third argument seems correct though, so I stand corrected. Strange that they don't even use session_start in the example in the manual.

Comment: @Emil Vikström: Another way would be to observe the HTTP response without and with calling `session_cache_limiter`. You will see that  there is no difference whether you call `session_cache_limiter` or not unless a session is started.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 lines in you're code, somewhere at the top of you're app

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
// this date can be set somewhere in the past
```